# Отличие URL адресов

Tags: php, localhost

Я установил программу EasyPHP 5.8.1. Запустил все активировано.

В моем самоучителе написано, что панель управления должна открываться по адресу:

```
http://loclhost/home
```

А у меня эта страница пуста! Она открывается только

```
http://localhost:8888     (про, что в книге не пишеться)
```

И в панели управления возле `localhost` стоит знак восклицания!

Как сделать, что бы панель EasyPHP открывалась по адресу:

```
http://locаlhost/home
```

Помогите, очень надо! Дальше весь самоучитель основан на EasyPHP.

Answer (score 2):

`http://localhost/` эквивалентно `http://localhost:80/`. Пропускается порт по умолчанию. У Вас веб-сервер по какой-то причине слушает на порту 8888, а не 80. Для разработки это никакого серьезного значения не имеет, так что особо не смущайтесь. Но если нужно перенести на 80-й порт — отредактируйте конфиг Apache (где он лежит, увы, не подскажу), найдя там директиву `Listen 8888` и поменяв номер порта на нужный.

Возможно (честно говорю, EasyPHP я в глаза не видел), Вы установили Apache от пользователя, а порты ниже 1024 могут использовать только администраторы, вот установщик и решил сделать чтобы работало хоть как-то и запустил на 8888 порту.

По второму моменту — слово «loclhost» — по всей видимости, опечатка. Но если очень хочется именно его — пропишите такое имя в `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` (`%SystemRoot%`, как правило, `C:\Windows\`) к именам для `127.0.0.1` (будет строчка в духе `127.0.0.1 localhost loclhost`)

Comment: Извините, была опечатка в слове "localhost".